# set a boolean true after scrolled 200px

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation and animated.Scrollview

I have this scrollview

```
<Animated.ScrollView 
        onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
            { useNativeDriver: false })}            
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
```

the constructor is:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      scrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
    }

    this.state.scrollY.addListener(value => {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({reverseColorValue: value.value > 200})
    })

  }
```

i use reverseColorValue for set reverseColor of icons of my header to true after that user scroll more of 200 px.

This mode works but is very very slow.
Is there a method to set reverseColorValue without use AddListener?
Or something that speed up it?

Answer (score 0):

You are running `setParams` in every scroll event. Below code might be a better performance since you wouldn't do unnecessary set actions.

```
// this might not be the exact behavior you want but its just an example of my idea
this.state.scrollY.addListener(value => {
    if (value.value > 200 && this.props.navigation.state.params.reverseColorValue === false) {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({reverseColorValue: true})
    } else if (value.value <= 200 && this.props.navigation.state.params.reverseColorValue === true) {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({reverseColorValue: false})
    }
})
```